# Instance Variable in JUnit

Tags: java, list, unit-testing, junit

I have a class that adds elements to a ArrayList (Instance Variable).
When I write a test case for the class using Junit, I initialize the class only once. I do the same work in both the test cases.

```
public class Solution {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void modifyList() {
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
    }
}
```

`SolutionTest.java`

```
public class TestSolution {

    Solution sol = new Solution();

    @Test
    public void testModifyList1() {
        sol.modifyList();
        Assert.assertEquals(3, sol.list.size());
        System.out.println(sol.list);
    }

    @Test
    public void testModifyList2() {
        sol.modifyList();
        Assert.assertEquals(3, sol.list.size());
        System.out.println(sol.list);
    }
}
```

When I print the list in both the test cases why doesnt the list when printed in the second test case return `[A, B, C, A, B, C]`. 
Why does it just return `[A, B, C]`. 
My understanding is that, the class is initialized only once, so there is only one copy of the list and it should be modified two times. But, when I print the list it prints only values modified from that test case. 
Can anyone please explain the behavior ?

**When I call the same method on the same object in two different test cases, why isn't the list being updated twice?**

Comment: both methods use sol.modifyList(); add element to arraylist

Comment: it is appending because `Solution` object is shared between two methods

Comment: @YamanJain I think the question asks same thing that - why is list not getting appended

Comment: That what private variable list is not re initialized

Comment: `sol` and `list` are instance variables, not static variables, so when you "initialize the class only once" it has absolutely no effect on instance variables, which aren't initialized until the _instance_ is, which is every test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for the `list` not being updated the second time is because of the behavior of `Junit`. `Junit` creates an instance of the test class for each test. So, a new object is created for each test case and the `list` is reinitialized every time.

Answer (score 2):

JUnit instantiate the test class once per test method. That means list will be created once per test, regardless of where you declare it.